# Creating MyTouch 3G Emulator

Tags: android, settings, emulation, screen-size, device-manager

What are the settings I need to create an emulator that mimics the HTC MyTouch 3G Slide Phone in the Android Virtual Device Manager?  The part I am most unsure about is which skin to use (HVGA, QVGA, WVGA...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [HTCs site](http://www.htc.com/us/products/t-mobile-mytouch-3g-slide/#tech-specs):

- 3.4-inch TFT-LCD touch-sensitive screen with 320 X 480 HVGA
  resolution

Comment: You forgot to mention that it should be running Android 2.1 or 2.2 (the only officially released builds for the MyTouch 3G and Eris (CDMA version).

Comment: How does the OS version impact the screen size and resolution?  It'd be phat if I could upgrade my myTouch from Froyo to GB and get a better res... guessing it doesn't work that way.

Comment: Obviously it doesn't, but if you're trying to emulate the actual device, you should match the OS version to the one installed on the actual devices.

Comment: I might not get ya, but screen resolutions don't improve as you upgrade your OS.  The actual hardware is the actual hardware...